# How do you move chests in your house?

Tags: stardew-valley

I figured out how to move furniture but I cannot move chests.  I tried both moving it and "gathering" it with various tools.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't played on the Switch, but on the PC version, you needed to take everything out of a chest before you could move it IIRC

Answer (score 0):

To pick up a chest, it must be empty (otherwise you'd have a "nesting doll" situation that gave you extra inventory space). You can move a non-empty chest without picking it up, however - walk up to the chest with nothing in your hands, and click repeatedly or click and hold on the chest. It will shake for a moment, and then jump one square away from you. If the chest would move into a wall, it will jump to the square behind you instead. This trick is very useful for making minor rearrangements without having to shuffle around lots of inventory items.